# unable to exchange auth token with access token - redirect uri missmatch

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I try to build below:

[image]

by following: [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) steps

however, i keep receiving redirect uri missmatch when i tried to exchange auth code (given by my mobile app) to google server - which i couldn't understand because technically there is no redirect uri required for my flow case...

here are the details:

in Android Client:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
        .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId, false)
        .build();
/**** bla.... ****/
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String authCode = acct.getServerAuthCode();
/**** android app will send this authCode to my server ****/
/**** sample authCode: 4/Jny2Mxxx3x09sy4pqY3ZAwSTEz8rw2xxxxC-4VxxxxM
```

in my backend server:

```
try:
    # i receive authCode correctly from android app.
    # and use authCode to exchange to Access Token to google server as below:
    credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
                  app.config.get('GG_APP_SECRET'),
                  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'profile', 'email'],
                  authCode)
except Exception as e:
    log.info('>>>>> I always receive: redirect uri missmatch here: %s <<<<<', e)
    return generate_response(code=400, error=False, type='Fail', message=str(e))
```

this is curl from my backend server:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "authCode": "4/HP_cP_t70pgBrxxx7sjzCil7kaUHkxxxerdkMxxxrRg" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:5005/api/user/register/gg'
```

this is my console settings:

[image]

Questions:

is the serverClientId in android client suppose to be the clientID of above image?

what is the redirect uri that i should put in google console above?

what should i set/configure for my redirect uri? or is there any specific settings that i need to do?

Comment: consider calling the http endpoints directly rather than trying to figure out what the library is doing. It just two simple http POSTS which you can see in the oauthplayground.

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem here is why google told me that uri missmatch? And i dont know what is redirect uri that i should put since for my case hybrid flow, there are no redirect uri.

Comment: how about  pasting your code so we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: @pinoyyid, sure, i have updated my question... please have a look and thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I go it,

if you see [this](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/oauth2client/client.html#credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code)

you will found out:

```
def credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(filename, scope, code,
                                            message=None,
                                            redirect_uri='postmessage',
                                            http=None,
                                            cache=None,
                                            device_uri=None):
```

and you realize that redirect_uri = 'postmessage' which in my case i dont have post message.

so what i do is to match that `redirect_uri` with `authorize redirect uri` that i have in google console

so for my case in my question above, i change my python code to:

```
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
                  app.config.get('GG_APP_SECRET'),
                  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'profile', 'email'],
                  authCode, redirect_uri='https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground')
```